# Getting [ng:test] no injector found for element argument to getTestability error when swithching between different single page applications

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am running tests on protractor. The website that I am testing bootstrapping angularjs manually. While running tests this is the error that I get even though steps keep on executing

```
Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page:
"[ng:test] no injector found for element argument to getTestability
\nhttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/test"
```

On going to the link 
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/test

The explanation that I am getting is this

```
Angular's testability helper, getTestability, requires a root
element to be passed in. This helps differentiate between different
Angular apps on the same page. 
This error is thrown when no injector is found for root element.
It is often because the root element is outside of the ng-app.
```

I get this error when I switch from one SPA to another. The website that I am testing doesn't use **ng-app** anywhere.

As far as I have understand that rootelement for ng-app is usually html or body

If I use body in my conf.js. I am able to run other tests succesfully but when I navigate from one SPA to another then the tests sometime gives the above error

This is my conf.js file

```
var customReport  = require('./Utilities/HtmlWriter.js').htmlWriter;

//config dependencies - all the js files  in tests folder ending with -spec.js will be executed
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', //Selenium webdriver instance needed to run the tsts
  specs: ['./tests/functional/EditAppInfo_spec.js'], // All tests need to be placed inside tests folder and should end with _spec.js

  baseUrl:'http://url.in.test.net',

      capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox',
    },

    /*
     multiCapabilities:[
      {
            'browserName': 'chrome'
       },
        {
            'browserName': 'firefox'
        },       
        {
           'browserName': 'internet explorer',
        }
    ],
    */  

  getPageTimeout:30000,
  allScriptsTimeout:30000,
  rootElement: "body",

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    onComplete: null,
    isVerbose: true,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 10000000000000
 },

         onPrepare: function() {
    }
};
```

Do I need to change the root element as I navigate in between different SPA's  using  in between spec files

```
browser.rootElement
```

Can anyone help me out on this. If I get the dev to put an ID on top of the div where the SPA is being loaded will that solve?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue now. Earlier I was testing an app whose body/div class was in the conf.js like this

rootElement: '.classOfDivUnderBodyOfAnSPA',

Now I am testing another app and I hot this and I commented this out and added

rootElement: '.classOfDivUnderBodyOfNewSPA',

this fixed the issue.

Note: I am not saying which element to look at (like body that you have).  I have the class value of the div under body. Hope this helps!

Revision: I added both the div together, comma seperated and that helped too. So no need to live with one or other.
rootElement: '.class1, .class2',

Comment: i tired the thing that you told me. Many of these errors have been solved but I am still getting the same error on firefox few times

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this error by changing the

```
`framework: jasmine`
```

property in my protractor.conf.js to

```
`framework: jasmine2`
```

Comment: Is the backquote intended?

Comment: No I don't think so